# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libXXXXX.so.0" not found 発生

Tags: android, android-studio

サードパーティコードをAndroid用にクロスコンパイルし **libXXXXX.so** を作成してみました。アプリはAndroid Studioでビルドは成功したのですが、アプリ実行時に以下にエラーになります。

logcat エラーログ

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libXXXXX.so.0" not found
```

libXXXXX.so.0 の **so.0** がなんとなく原因と思っているのですが、Android Studioで対処方法がわからずにいます。

readelfコマンドで見ると以下です。

```
$readelf -d libXXXXX.so | grep SONAME
0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libXXXXX.so.0]
```

CMakeLists.txtは以下です

```
add_library( libXXXXX SHARED IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( libXXXXX
    PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIB_ROOT}/cpp/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libXXXXX.so )

add_library(hello-jni SHARED src/main/cpp/hello-jni.cpp )

target_link_libraries( hello-jni libXXXXX ${log-lib} )
```

Java コードは以下です。

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
```

・libXXXXX.so.0 も so ファイルと同じ場所に置いてもエラーのままでした。
・また libXXXXX.a(STATIC LIBRARY)の場合も試し、これは実行も正常に出来ました。

CMakeLists.txtにSONAME関連のオプションを付けたりするのでは？と思い調べたのですが、よくわかりませんでした。解決方法をよろしくお願いいたします。

**状況が変わりました。**

loadLibraryを行っていませんでした。

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("XXXXX");
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
```

新たなlogcat エラーログ

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol **"acos"** referenced by "...libXXXXX.so"...
```

acos がないエラーなのですが、Androidに acos は存在しないのでしょうか？解決は難しいでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

**以下のように変更してみましたが、状況は変わりません（同じエラーのまま）**

CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries( hello-jni libXXXXX m ${log-lib} )
```

Java コード

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("m");
    System.loadLibrary("XXXXX");
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
```

引き続きよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `acos(arc cosine)` なので libm.so もリンクする必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。libm.soについて調査しますので、また結果を報告いたします。少々お時間をください。

Comment: 本文に追記しました。同じエラーのままでした。

Comment: 他ライブラリをふんだんに使っているNativeコードをクロスコンパイルして使用することは、どツボにはまりやすく、おススメしません。他の代替え方法を考えるのが得策と言えそうです。ということで解決とします。

Answer (score 1):

自分も同じような問題で調べていてたどり着きました。
API24以降の制限についてのこんな資料を見つけました。
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/372f19e/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#private-api-enforced-for-api-level-24

> ネイティブライブラリは、パブリックAPIのみを使用し、非NDKプラットフォームライブラリとはリンクしてはいけません。API 24
> からはこのルールが適用され、アプリケーションは非NDKプラットフォームライブラリを読み込むことができなくなりました。このルールはダイナミックリンカーによって強制されるため、コードがどのように読み込もうとしたかにかかわらず、パブリックでないライブラリにはアクセスできません。System.loadLibrary、DT_NEEDED
> エントリ、および dlopen(3) の直接呼び出しは、すべてまったく同じように動作します。